# Unlimited paired variables through .htaccess

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

This may be asked already but I'm struggling on here and can't figure it out,
I'm not really good with .htaccess

I'm working on an API and would like to accept multiple variables such as

> http://www.website.com/api/CONTROLLER/person/id/1/sort/name/limit/2

and would like to obtain something like

```
$_REQUEST['CONTROLLER']=person;
$_REQUEST['id']=1;
$_REQUEST['sort']=name;
$_REQUEST['limit']=2;
```

I'm currently doing this through php using `$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]` and explode, but would like to find out if there is a way to do it on .htaccess directly

If you know which one will perform best would be glad to hear it out!

Comment: It *could* be done using mod_rewrite, yes, but doing so seems awfully complex and limited. It's typically better done using a *router* implemented in PHP.

Comment: @deceze so you believe it will perform better that way or it's going to be simpler to just keep it as it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^api/([^/]+)/([^/]+)(/.*)? /api/$3?$1=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Assuming that your php script is the index.php file in your `/api/` directory. Otherwise, you'd need to also include (at the end):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .+
RewriteRule ^api/$ /path/to/your/script.php [L,QSA]
```

Note that this relies on the mod_rewrite engine looping internally. There's a server setting which limits the maximum number of internal redirects, and if the URL is really long, it'll hit the internal recursion limit and return a 500. You can change this using the [LimitInternalRecursion](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#limitinternalrecursion) directive.

Comment: Hi Jon Lin, it's in /api/index.php but yours api is giving me a NOT FOUND, I also tried
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php/$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^api/([^/]+)/([^/]+)(/.*)? /api/$3?$1=$2 [L,QSA]
But didn't work either

Comment: This is probably happening because of PATH_INFO. The index.php is being executed right off the bat and the rules probably aren't being applied. `!-f` won't help either because `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` considers that there is an `index.php` in the /api/` directory. You could try renaming `index.php` to something else and using the 2nd rule.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, and sorry for taking your time, but I couldn't make it work :(, tested with /api/script.php api/script.php and /var/www/html/api/script.php on all cases I got a not found page

Comment: @Saikios the htaccess file is in your document root (`/var/www/html/`) right? And make sure you have mod_rewrite loaded, too.

Comment: yes it's I don't have access to the ssh in this server, but your answer was great! thanks for the help, only one small question what do you beleive would perform better the rewrites or using php and why? (if you want to answer of course!)

Comment: @Saikios I don't know what the benchmarks are of using mod_rewrite vs php are. There's probably a lot of things that go into it, like caching. I doubt there's very much difference unless microseconds matter.